# Pass async function (changes channel name) into thread

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py

I'm trying to pass an async function into a @tasks.loop thread since my commands don't work until the task is finished, if threading isn't used. However the task I'm trying to do every 5 minutes is to change the channel name, and it doesn't work. I get a `Timeout context manager should be used` error.

```py
async def change_name()
  channel = client.get_channel(chid)
  await chid.edit(name='yes')

@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def loop():
  _thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run,args=())
  _thread.start()

loop.start()
```

Comment: Maybe: [`loop.run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

Comment: I got the error: Loop has no attribute run in executor

Comment: Read the link, don't blindly copy code! *(which was even real code but the name of the function)*

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll try it again

Comment: whats your reasoning to use threading here? there’s no need for that.

Comment: I usually have people using commandsm and the commands don't work until the loop is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `python-worker` for it ([link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/))

```
from worker import async_worker

@async_worker
async def change_name()
  channel = client.get_channel(chid)
  await chid.edit(name='yes')

@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def loop():
    await change_name()

loop.start()
```

your `change_name` will be run as thread automatically